# Can I attach a dagger to the end of a polearm for use with the Polearm Master feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, weapons

In Dungeons and Dragons 5e my character uses a glaive with the polearm master feat that allows for a bonus action strike with the blunt end. Recently I acquired a dagger of venom and have a forge cleric in my party. Would I be able to attach the dagger to the end of my glaive for use with the PAM bonus action strike, or is there a rule which prohibits this?

Comment: Hi Vick, welcome to RPG.SE. This is an interesting question involving creative use of equipment. I have edited your question to make what you are asking more clear. Feel free to revert the edit if I have accidentally changed the meaning of your question. If you haven't already, I encourage you to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feat description itself describes what you can do and leaves no room for replacement of the blunt end you use for the bonus action attack.

> When you take the Attack action and attack with only a **glaive, halberd, quarterstaff, or spear**, you can use a bonus action to make a melee attack with the opposite end of the weapon. The weapon's damage die for this attack is a d4, and the **attack deals bludgeoning damage**.

#### Why MacGyvering doesn't work here:

- Modifying the weapon results in a weapon that is no longer a halberd, glaive quarterstaff or spear. You're trying to add the dagger as integral part of the weapon, but the definitions of the weapons that allow you to do this does not include a dagger affixed to the end of the shaft.
- The feat tells that the damage is bludgeoning damage. Even if you could create some kind of double weapon that would work with Pole Arm Master, this does not change the feat description.
- There are no rules for combining magical items with other ones (magical or not) (at least none that I know of). Since you would be creating an item that would greatly enhance the capabilities of your character, a DM should be very careful with this, since it has a fair chance of unbalancing the game.

Comment: The [errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) of 11/18 rewords the feat slightly: *"Both instances of “or quarterstaff” have been changed to “quarterstaff, or spear.”"* I don't know if that changes your answer any, since a spear is basically a dagger on the end of a pole, but I thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: @keithcurtis Thx, included the new version in the quote. This does not change the answer however. A spear with 2 pointy ends would either be used as spear and the best result you could get (if the DM allows it) would be a spear of venom, still resulting in the bonus attack dealing bludgeoning damage. If you use both pointy ends, the fighting style would have to be significantly different and would no longer qualify as any of the weapons.

Comment: Agreed from a technical perspective, but the rules should never prevent reasonable cleverness. Just strapping the dagger to the end of the pole makes it an improvised weapon, as others have noted. I'd require a blacksmith to modify the end cap and overrule the 'attack deals bludgeoning damage' and make it a spear strike because the concerns favor RAW in general shouldn't stop us from applying good sense. As for the balance concerns, well this is how innovation happens. The first sword was an unfair advantage for the first swordsman, but they got popular pretty fast. Same would happen here..

Comment: To add, I might also give the glaive/dagger combo attacks at disadvantage until a new proficiency could be acquired to take full advantage of it. The weapon's balance would change, and new options open up and other options cease to be viable with this modification. Plus the wielder risks cutting himself open with the dagger-end.

Answer (score 5):

A dagger attached to your glaive sounds like a definitive [Improvised Weapon](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Weapons#toc_14):

> Often, an Improvised Weapon is similar to an actual weapon and can be treated as such. For example, a table leg is akin to a club. **At the GM’s option**, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

If your DM is happy to call your dagger on a stick a polearm then you would get the benefit of polearm master.

Comment: Vick can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe what the querent specifically wants to know is whether you can use the dagger of venom (improvised in this way) as part of the bonus action attack granted by polearm master.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned, putting it on a stick to use as a polearm would call for improvised weapon use at best, and attaching it to the tail of another polearm is neither RAW nor a good idea to allow.

Now, finding a real skilled blacksmith to work the magic dagger into a halberd's blade to get a halberd of the same effect? That's entirely up to DM, but a wonderful plot hook.